# How to replace two different expressions that match start of the string by null using string.replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to replace the mime at the start of the string by null..
The two mime regular expressions to match the start of the string are
/^data:audio/x-ms-wma\w*;base64,/

and

/^data:audio/\w+;base64,/

Can anyone suggest a way by which I can combine the above two and replace both if found by null..
Individually I have used

```
var b64Data=text.replace(/^data:audio\/\w+;base64,/, '');
```

to replace the expression if found, by null..how can i combine both the regular expressions and replace both by null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `|` to list alternatives in a regular expression.

```
var b64Data = text.replace(/^data:audio\w+;base64,|^data:audio\/x-ms-wma\w*;base64,/,'');
```

Comment: This means that both too little and too much explanation is bad.